# Apache-Beam exception while running WordCount example in eclipse

Tags: apache-beam

Downloaded maven dependecies in eclipse using

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
<artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
<version>0.2.0-incubating</version></dependency>
```

When download and run  [WordCount](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/incubator-beam/release-0.2.0-incubating/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/WordCount.java) example after changing the gs path to the C://examples//misc.txt.Getting the below exception.I did not pass any runner.How to pass the runner option and output params while running from eclipse??

```
    SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to validate C://examples//misc.txt
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO$Read$Bound.apply(TextIO.java:288)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO$Read$Bound.apply(TextIO.java:195)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.PipelineRunner.apply(PipelineRunner.java:76)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectRunner.apply(DirectRunner.java:205)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:401)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:324)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PBegin.apply(PBegin.java:59)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.apply(Pipeline.java:174)
    at org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:206)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to find handler for C://examples//misc.txt
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.IOChannelUtils.getFactory(IOChannelUtils.java:188)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.TextIO$Read$Bound.apply(TextIO.java:283)
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe Apache Beam will parse syntax `C://directory/file` similar to `http://domain/file` -- it will think that `C` is a protocol name and that `directory` is a domain. The inner exception is saying that `C` is an unknown protocol.

Please try to avoid using `://` symbol when referring to local files. I'd suggest using regular Windows standard: `C:\directory\file`.

Comment: It gave the output well with argument --output=C:\\dir\\beam_material\\result. but getting an exception while removing the temp files as                                                                                       **_Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <*> at index 46: C:\\dir\\beam_material\\result-temp-*
  at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:18)            at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileBasedSink$FileBasedWriteOperation.removeTemporaryFiles(FileBasedSink.java:392)_**

Comment: The exception during cleanup is a bug. I've filed [BEAM-863](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-863) issue, marked blocking for the 0.4.0 release. Please watch/comment there for updates. Sorry about that!

Comment: The output of word count is being printed in 4 different files. Is it supposed to be printed in one file? How can I do it.. Is there any specific steps I am missing?

Comment: Yes -- this is normal. It is even mentioned in the [Quickstart](http://beam.incubator.apache.org/get-started/quickstart/). The exact number of these files is decided by the runner, giving it the flexibility to do efficient, distributed execution. You can use `withNumShards` API to control this somewhat, but that sometimes comes with a performance cost, depending on several factors.

Comment: Ok. However the end user(developer) does not have control on where these files are located in the cluster. Then how can he aggregate the results from different files into one file as output ? t.(In MapReduce API, it has an API to reduce the output of mappers into a single file)

Comment: Can we move this into a separate question? This is very far from where we started.

Comment: @Devor Can you please help me on this question also .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525269/jdbc-fetch-from-oracle-with-beam/40536963#40536963

Comment: Thanks @naga; I'll make sure the question is answered shortly.