# JDBC Fetch from oracle with Beam

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

The below program is to connect to Oracle 11g and fetch the records. How ever it is giving me NullPointerException for the coder at pipeline.apply().

I have added the ojdbc14.jar to the project dependencies.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(PipelineOptionsFactory.create());      
         p.apply(JdbcIO.<KV<Integer, String>>read()
                   .withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create(
                          "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@hostdnsname:port/servicename")
                   .withUsername("uname")
                   .withPassword("pwd"))
                   .withQuery("select EMPID,NAME from EMPLOYEE1")
                   .withRowMapper(new JdbcIO.RowMapper<KV<Integer, String>>() {
                     public KV<Integer, String> mapRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {
                       return KV.of(resultSet.getInt(1), resultSet.getString(2));
                     }
                   }));
         p.run();

    }
```

is giving the below error.Any clue?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: coder
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:228)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$Read.validate(JdbcIO.java:283)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO$Read.validate(JdbcIO.java:216)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyInternal(Pipeline.java:399)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline.java:307)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PBegin.apply(PBegin.java:47)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.apply(Pipeline.java:158)
    at org.apache.beam.examples.v030.JdbcUtil.main(JdbcUtil.java:21)
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi there!

Sorry the error message is not very helpful, but in fact it is a validation step. I have filed [BEAM-959](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-959) to improve this.

You are required to provide a coder such as via

```java
.withCoder(KvCoder.of(VarIntCoder.of(), StringUtf8Coder.of())`
```

I have filed [BEAM-960](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-960) to improve automation of this coder, like we have in most other places in Beam.

Comment: I have edited your post above.after making the changes above. It is giving the below error.                                                                                                            Exception in thread "main" org.apache.beam.runners.direct.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z

Comment: Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: @ Kenn ,To resolve the problem, let me know if you need any additional info.

Comment: Your further issue is unrelated to this question. It could be related to staging or versioning of the JDBC driver. Can you open a new question for that? (and possibly accept this answer :-)

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
 pipeline.apply(( JdbcIO.<KV<Integer, String>>read().withCoder(KvCoder.of(VarIntCoder.of(),StringUtf8Coder.of())) 
               .withDataSourceConfiguration(JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create(
                      "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/deepakgoyal")
                    .withUsername("root")
                    .withPassword("root"))
               .withQuery("select empid, name from employee")

               .withRowMapper(new JdbcIO.RowMapper<KV<Integer, String>>() {
                 public KV<Integer, String> mapRow(ResultSet resultSet) throws Exception {
                   return KV.of(resultSet.getInt(1), resultSet.getString(2));
                 }
               })
             ))
```

And don't forget to add MySQL connector jar in your project.

Comment: Apologies, But i did not understood what exactly you want.